# Java Map returns null for a present key

Tags: java, string, dictionary, null

I'm having a very unusual problem.
Basically, I'm trying to get the value associated with a key from a Map of Strings to Strings.
I know that the key I'm using is present; I'm using the same string I used to put it in!

I've print statements all over my code, and this is case I have...
Here is my dictionary ***characterDictionary***

```
{thusChar=∴, spaceChar= , plusChar=+, equalsIndent=#, multiplyChar=×, equalsChar==, newlineChar=\n, divideChar=÷, subjectChar=:, variableIndent=@}
```

The very last key "variableIndent" is the trouble!
Here's the code...

```
System.out.println  (   characterDictionary.get("variableIndent") );
```

which inappropriately outputs:  `null`

I have checked, double checked and triple checked my code.
There is absolutely no difference between the key ***"variableIndent"*** and the string argument of `characterDictionary.get("variableIndent")`, yet it's behaving as if this key was not present.

I can absolutely guarantee this key is present, and that the two strings are identical.
All the other elements (the ones I've checked; about 3 so far) of the dictionary are retrieved as normal. Why is "variableIndent" with it's "@" value playing up?

You might notice the dictionary contains non ASCII characters, like "thusChar". Could this be related?

Thanks
(This seems like a very simple and trivial problem, as if I've made some pitifully silly mistake, but yet I just can't solve it!)

**EDIT:**

Okay, this HAS to be something about encoding.
I took the string key from the dictionary and compared it to my get argument.
When printed, they are identical, but java says they are not equal.
The key string came from a UTF-8 encoded text file, whilst the argument string came from a java Eclipse literal.
The characters are identical however.
What is the issue, and how can I resolve it?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Hmmm, here's what's actually happening behind the scenes.
I have a UTF-8 text file which contains the following content...

```
variableIndent,@
equalsIndent,#
spaceChar, 
newlineChar,\n
multiplyChar,×
divideChar,÷
plusChar,+
equalsChar,=
subjectChar,:
thusChar,∴
```

I 'load' this file by reading in each line of the file as an `ArrayList<String>` element, by passing the directory of the file:

```
private static ArrayList<String> readLinesFile(String ResourceFile)  {
    ArrayList<String> Lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            InputStream fstream = FileManager.class.getResourceAsStream(ResourceFile);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine;
            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)  {
                Lines.add(strLine);  } 
            in.close();  }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());  } 
        return Lines;  }
```

Everything is fine up to here.
I then pass this ArrayList into a function that splits up each element by the "," character (using a function from a personal package; It is definitely not the issue), and adds the first part as a key to the second in the new dictionary.

```
private static Map<String, String> generateBaseUnits_Characters_Prefixes(ArrayList<String> FileContent)  {
    Map<String, String> BaseUnitsCache = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ArrayList<String> currentLine;
    for (int i=0; i<FileContent.size(); i++)  {
        currentLine = MiscellaneousFunctions.splitString(FileContent.get(i), ",");
        BaseUnitsCache.put(currentLine.get(0), currentLine.get(1)); }
    return BaseUnitsCache;  }
```

and this produces the dictionary that is causing all the trouble.
I have a set of Key Literals that correspond to the character names in the text files, which I use to access the dictionary in the program.

```
public static String variableIndentKey = "variableIndent";
public static String equalsIndentKey = "equalsIndent";
public static String spaceCharKey = "spaceChar";  
public static String newlineCharKey = "newlineChar";
public static String multiplyCharKey = "multiplyChar";
public static String divideCharKey = "divideChar";  
public static String plusCharKey = "plusChar";
public static String equalsCharKey = "equalsChar";  
public static String subjectCharKey = "subjectChar";
public static String thusCharKey = "thusChar";
```

***HERE'S THE PROBLEM:***

The top line of the textfile 'screws up' in the dictionary.
It is added to the dictionary and appears correctly amongst the keySet and the printed format of the dictionary, but trying to access it returns "null".
(In this case, it's variableIndent. If I put variableIndent somewhere else in the text file, equalsIndent screws up, etc)

What's going on!?
Do I have a dodgy function?!
They've worked well for everything else.

Thanks!

Comment: In order to guarantee that this key is present, iterate over all the keys in this map and print their value.

Comment: Can you show some that reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: edited the OP. Believe it to be an encoding issue between a textfile and Eclipse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change you UTF-8 text file which contains the key and value to UTF-8 without BOM.
There are three bytes(UTF-8 BOM 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF before "variableIndent")
see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: How on Earth do I go about doing that?

Comment: @AntiEarth This may help... Anyway, if you find solution please inform also me. I'm curious how will you solve such strange issue. Sadly there isn't anyway automatic way to fallow questions on SO.

Comment: This has fixed the issue! I opened my text file in Notepad ++, changed the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM, and re-saved the file. These annoying characters disappeared, and everything is back to normal.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are afraid of encoding issues (that seems to be the problem here), you have to make sure your project's encoding is set to `UTF-8`. To check it, go to **Project** menu, and choose **Properties**. It may be required to change **text file encoding** from `Inherited from container` to `Oher: UTF-8`

Comment: Done. Still no success. I'm absolutely stumped.

Comment: @Anti Earth I suppose that you should print `hashCode()` of "both" Strings - this1 from map, and this1 that you search for and end with nothing. They should be the same, if it is the same String.

Comment: Explored this in other answers; they are not the same string. Whichever line from the text file is processed first and added to the dictionary first, somehow 'mutates' in a hidden way. Still don't know how or why.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at your code in a debugger. I suspect the map is not what you think it is.

```
String data = "{thusChar=∴, spaceChar= , plusChar=+, equalsIndent=#, multiplyChar=×, equalsChar==, newlineChar=\\n, divideChar=÷, subjectChar=:, variableIndent=@}";
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for (String keyValue : data.substring(1, data.length() - 1).split(", ")) {
    String[] parts = keyValue.split("=", 2);
    map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
}
System.out.println("variableIndent is " + map.get("variableIndent"));
```

prints

```
variableIndent is @
```

---

can you try

```
for(String key: map.keySet())
   System.out.println("'"+key+"'= "+map.get(key));
```

Comment: printed the KeySet and received '[thusChar, spaceChar, plusChar, equalsIndent, multiplyChar, equalsChar, newlineChar, divideChar, subjectChar, variableIndent]'

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try this code and let us know the output

```
for (String key : characterDictionary.keySet() ) {
System.out.println(key);
}

for ( String value :  characterDictionary.values() ) {
System.out.println(value);
}
```

P.S: Might want to change Type of key and value.

Comment: thusChar
spaceChar
plusChar
equalsIndent
multiplyChar
equalsChar
newlineChar
divideChar
subjectChar
variableIndent
∴
 
+
#
×
=
\n
÷
:
@

Exactly as expected!
I'll try with the key changd

Comment: Grr thought I had it figured out. Any chance you can post your code where you're creating and initializing the characterDictionary?

Answer (score 0):

If you think it's an encoding issue, then try using the following methods to compare the actual content, irrespective of what it looks like.

Use `getBytes()` to get all the bytes from both Strings (the key from the map, as well as the string in your code), and print

1. The length of the byte array
2. Each byte as an integer

Then use `getChars()` to get all the chars from both Strings or `charAt()` to read each char, and print

1. Each char as an integer.

Between these two checks you should be able to figure out how both strings are different at a byte level. What's the character-set that the file is saved in?

**EDIT**

I suspect your use of DataInputStream is causing problems with the bytes being read.

```
InputStream fstream = FileManager.class.getResourceAsStream(ResourceFile);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

The Java docs for DataInputStream say "A data input stream lets an application read primitive Java data types from an underlying input stream in a machine-independent way. An application uses a data output stream to write data that can later be read by a data input stream." You're not reading from a DataOutputStream here, just a regular file.
Also, you already have an InputStream for the InputStreamReader to use. Change your code to this:

```
InputStream fstream = FileManager.class.getResourceAsStream(ResourceFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
```

**EDIT 2**

Another thing worth doing, since your string from the text file is 3 bytes longer, is changing this

```
BaseUnitsCache.put(currentLine.get(0), currentLine.get(1));
```

to

```
BaseUnitsCache.put(currentLine.get(0).trim(), currentLine.get(1).trim());
```

Comment: I've an update to the problem that makes me think encoding may no longer be relevant :P

Comment: Certainly! (Sorry, I'm notably slow at everything ever)

Comment: What did converting the String from the file to bytes give you? How many bytes does it have, and what's the first one?

Comment: Wait, what are you using DataInputStream for? Why not get rid of it completely and just use BufferedReader?

Comment: This is me with Java file reading
http://www.kulfoto.com/pic/0001/0015/L80Cl14168.jpg

It's worked for all other file IO in my program. I'll change it when this bug is resolved, if you recommend.

Comment: I followed your advice and was shocked to find that the apparently identical strings are different in getBytes().length.
The dictionary key string has 17 bytes, and the literal 14. What does this mean?!

Comment: Can you link me to any examples? I'd very much like an output of an ArrayList of Strings, and my incapability of learning / finding the correct method is probably what lead me to use data input stream  :P

Comment: Used your suggestion, problem still exists! Is there anything at all I should know about the first line of a UTF-8 text file? Is it special?

Comment: I have been going through removing misuse of DataInputStream for reading text as there is so many bad examples, it needs to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way...

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();


for (Map.Entry<String, String> mp : map.entrySet()){


  System.out.println("Key: "+mp.key()+"::"+"Value: "+mp.value());


}
```